# Scroll up in Rich Text Editor at all saves - Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, editor, rich-text-editor, sitecore-sxa

Where? **Rich Editor**

*Describe bug:* When I make a change to a post - for example, add a link, add an image, change a paragraph style - once I click "OK" to save the change, the page pulls me back to the first paragraph.

*How to replicate:* Make a change related to style or link in the rich editor.

Answer (score 0):

**In:**

> [your-website]\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\EditorPage.aspx

**Change from:**

```
<script>
 fixFirefoxPaste();
</script>
```

**To:**

```
<script>
fixFirefoxPaste();

Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.DomRange.prototype.scrollIntoView = function(s) {
    var r = s.anchorNode.parentNode;
    if ((r.tagName.toLowerCase() != "body" && r.tagName.toLowerCase() != "html") && r.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded) {
        r.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
    }
}
</script>
```